# Unable to create queues in ActiveMQ broker

Tags: queue, activemq-classic

In one of the ActiveMQ instance (v5.13.3), when tried to create a queue manually using Web console, getting error as shown below [image: Error]

Within the ActiveMQ logs, there is no errors but an warn as below. This instance is working fine for the existing queues & topics. Only facing problem while trying a new queue. Even the restart doesn't the help. With the similar setup it works fine in another instances.

```
2018-07-05 14:42:49,700 | WARN  | /admin/createDestination.action | org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler | qtp2076549461-5084797
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:438)[:1.8.0_112]
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:416)[:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.RecoverableRandomAccessFile.readFully(RecoverableRandomAccessFile.java:75)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.PageFile.readPage(PageFile.java:878)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction$2.readPage(Transaction.java:456)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction$2.<init>(Transaction.java:447)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.openInputStream(Transaction.java:444)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.load(Transaction.java:420)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.load(Transaction.java:377)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.index.BTreeIndex.loadNode(BTreeIndex.java:266)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.index.BTreeNode.getChild(BTreeNode.java:233)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.index.BTreeNode.getLast(BTreeNode.java:624)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.index.BTreeIndex.getLast(BTreeIndex.java:248)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase$MessageOrderIndex.addLast(MessageDatabase.java:3298)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase$MessageOrderIndex.configureLast(MessageDatabase.java:3289)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.loadStoredDestination(MessageDatabase.java:2346)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.getStoredDestination(MessageDatabase.java:2298)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore$7.execute(KahaDBStore.java:722)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore$7.execute(KahaDBStore.java:716)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.page.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:802)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore.recoverMessageStoreStatistics(KahaDBStore.java:716)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.AbstractMessageStore.start(AbstractMessageStore.java:45)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore.start(KahaDBStore.java:671)[activemq-kahadb-store-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.store.ProxyMessageStore.start(ProxyMessageStore.java:75)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.initialize(Queue.java:385)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.DestinationFactoryImpl.createDestination(DestinationFactoryImpl.java:87)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.createDestination(AbstractRegion.java:629)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedQueueRegion.createDestination(ManagedQueueRegion.java:56)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.addDestination(AbstractRegion.java:155)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.addDestination(RegionBroker.java:348)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:173)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisoryBroker.addDestination(AdvisoryBroker.java:239)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:173)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.addDestination(BrokerFilter.java:173)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addDestination(MutableBrokerFilter.java:178)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.BrokerView.addQueue(BrokerView.java:405)[activemq-broker-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.DestinationFacade.addDestination(DestinationFacade.java:56)[activemq-web-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.controller.CreateDestination.handleRequest(CreateDestination.java:38)[file:/C:/Talend/6.2.1/esb/activemq/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/classes/:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)[spring-webmvc-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)[spring-webmvc-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)[spring-webmvc-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)[spring-webmvc-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:867)[spring-webmvc-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)[tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.24.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)[spring-webmvc-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)[tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.24.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.AuditFilter.doFilter(AuditFilter.java:59)[activemq-web-5.13.3.jar:5.13.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:102)[file:/C:/Talend/6.2.1/esb/activemq/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/classes/:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_112]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNbCT.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is due to corrupted kahadb database files of the Active MQ. Copied the kahadb folder from another runtime instance (similar setup) and restarted the Active MQ service. This issue is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly because of incompatible Jetty version with JDK 1.8. You can resolve this
either by downgrading the JDK version to 1.7 and the set the JAVA_HOME or by upgrading the Jetty compatible with JDK 1.8.

I have got the similar issue with activemq version 5.10.0. Web console was working fine with JDK 1.7 but throwing an exception for JDK 1.8.